# Game server packet handler

Tags: java, game, multithreading

I am developing an online game and my code is getting pretty hard to work with. I would appreciate any suggestions how to clean it up or make it simpler to work with. Thanks for any suggestions.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import server.engine.*;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class ServerPacketHandler extends PacketHandler {

    public static CopyOnWriteArrayList<User> usersOnline = new CopyOnWriteArrayList();

    @Override
    public void handlePacket(Packet p) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
        ArrayList<String> newcontent = new ArrayList();
        for (String c : p.content) {
            newcontent.add(c.replace("<html>", "").replace("</html>", ""));
        }
        p.content = newcontent.toArray(new String[newcontent.size()]);
        if(Server.debugMode) CustomLog.info(p.id + " " + Arrays.toString(p.content));
        if (!p.user.isLogged) {
            switch (p.id) {
                case 0: { //user sent login information
                    if (!p.content[2].equals(Server.version)) {
                        p.user.sendPacket(-2);
                        return;
                    }
                    User user;
                    if ((user = UserManager.loadUser(p.content[0])) != null) {
                        if (!p.content[1].equals(user.password)) {
                            p.user.sendPacket(-1, "Incorrect login");
                            return;
                        }
                        p.user.isLogged = true;
                        p.user.id = p.content[0];
                        p.user.password = p.content[1];
                        if (user.username.equals("null")) {
                            p.user.sendPacket(2);
                        } else {
                            for (User u : usersOnline) {
                                if (u.username.equals(user.username)) {
                                    p.user.sendPacket(-1, "This username is already online!");
                                    u.sendPacket(-1, "You were disconnected from the server!");
                                    p.user.isLogged = false;
                                    try {
                                        p.user.socket.close();
                                        u.socket.close();
                                    } catch (IOException ex) {
                                        Logger.getLogger(ServerPacketHandler.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                                    }
                                    onClientDisconnected(p.user);
                                    onClientDisconnected(u);
                                    return;
                                }
                            }
                            p.user.username = user.username;
                            p.user.sendPacket(3, p.user.username);
                        }
                    } else {
                        p.user.sendPacket(-1, "Incorrect login");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 1: { //user requested registration
                    if (!p.content[0].equals(Server.version)) {
                        p.user.sendPacket(-2);
                        return;
                    }
                    String id = Integer.toString(UserGenerator.randInt());
                    String password = UserGenerator.randString();
                    while (UserManager.loadUser(id) != null) {
                        id = Integer.toString(UserGenerator.randInt());
                        password = UserGenerator.randString();
                    }
                    p.user.id = id;
                    p.user.password = password;
                    UserManager.saveUser(p.user);
                    p.user.sendPacket(1, id, password);
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else if (p.user.username.equals("null")) {
            switch (p.id) {
                case 2: { //user wants to setup username
                    if (p.content[0].length() < 15 && p.content[0].length() > 2 && p.content[0].matches("^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$") && !p.content[0].equals("null")) {
                        boolean found = false;
                        for (User u : UserManager.loadAllUsers()) {
                            if (u.username.equals(p.content[0])) {
                                found = true;
                            }
                        }

                        if (found) {
                            p.user.sendPacket(-1, "This username already exists.");
                            return;
                        }
                        p.user.username = p.content[0];
                        UserManager.saveUser(p.user);
                        p.user.sendPacket(3, p.user.username);
                    } else {
                        p.user.sendPacket(-1, "Incorrect username");
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            switch (p.id) {
                case 10: { //match list request
                    for (ServerMatch match : ServerMatch.matchList) {
                        if (!match.ingame) {
                            p.user.sendPacket(10, Integer.toString(match.id), match.name, match.host.username, match.password.equals("") ? "false" : "true", match.userList.size() + "/" + match.maxplayers, Integer.toString(match.time), Integer.toString(match.maxquestions), match.topics.toString());
                        }
                    }
                    p.user.sendPacket(11);
                    break;
                }
                case 15: { //match connect request
                    if (p.content[0].matches("^[0-9]*$")) {
                        ServerMatch m = ServerMatch.getMatch(Integer.parseInt(p.content[0]));
                        if (m != null && !m.ingame) {
                            if (m.password.equals("")) {
                                p.user.connectMatch(m);
                            } else if (p.content.length > 1 && m.password.equals(p.content[1])) {
                                p.user.connectMatch(m);
                            } else {
                                p.user.sendPacket(-1, "Wrong password!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 16: { //match disconnect request
                    p.user.disconnectMatch();
                    break;
                }
                case 20: { //create new match
                    boolean found = false;
                    for (ServerMatch match : ServerMatch.matchList) {
                        if (match.host == p.user) {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!found) {
                        if (!p.content[2].matches("^[0-9]*$") || !p.content[3].matches("^[0-9]*$") || !p.content[4].matches("^[0-9]*$") || p.content[5].equals("")) {
                            p.user.sendPacket(-3);
                            return;
                        }
                        String matchname = p.content[0];
                        String password = p.content[1];
                        int maxplayers = Integer.parseInt(p.content[2]);
                        int time = Integer.parseInt(p.content[3]);
                        int count = Integer.parseInt(p.content[4]);
                        String[] topics = p.content[5].split(";");
                        if (matchname.length() < 30 && matchname.length() > 2 && password.length() < 30 && count > 0 && count < 101 && maxplayers < 11 && maxplayers > 1 && time < 61 && time > 4) {
                            ServerMatch match = new ServerMatch(matchname, p.user);
                            if (!password.equals("[null]")) {
                                match.password = password;
                            }
                            match.time = time;
                            match.maxplayers = maxplayers;
                            match.maxquestions = count;
                            if(Arrays.asList(topics).contains("Custom")) { match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Custom); if(p.content.length < 7)  p.user.sendPacket(-3); }
                            else for (String topic : topics) {

                                switch (topic) {
                                    case "General":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.General);
                                        break;
                                    case "Technology":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Technology);
                                        break;
                                    case "History":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.History);
                                        break;
                                    case "Geography":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Geography);
                                        break;
                                    case "Sport":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Sport);
                                        break;
                                    case "Custom":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Custom);
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        p.user.sendPacket(-3);
                                        return;
                                }
                            }
                            if (match.topics.contains(Question.Topic.Custom)) {
                                if (p.content[6].length() > 5000) {
                                    p.user.sendPacket(-3);
                                    return;
                                }
                                ArrayList<Question> list = parseQuestions(p.content[6]);
                                if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) {
                                    p.user.sendPacket(-3);
                                    return;
                                }
                                match.customQuestions = list;
                            }
                            ServerMatch.matchList.add(match);
                            p.user.connectMatch(match);
                        } else {
                            p.user.sendPacket(-3);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 21: { //modify match
                    if (p.user.match != null && p.user==p.user.match.host && !p.user.match.ingame) {
                        if (!p.content[2].matches("^[0-9]*$") || !p.content[3].matches("^[0-9]*$") || p.content[4].equals("")) {
                            p.user.sendPacket(-1, "Match settings are not correct or custom questions are empty or failed to load.");
                            return;
                        }
                        String matchname = p.content[0];
                        String password = p.content[1];
                        int time = Integer.parseInt(p.content[2]);
                        int count = Integer.parseInt(p.content[3]);
                        String[] topics = p.content[4].split(";");
                        if (matchname.length() < 30 && matchname.length() > 2 && password.length() < 30 && count > 0 && count < 101 && time < 61 && time > 4) {
                            ServerMatch match = p.user.match;
                            if(match.customQuestions.isEmpty() && Arrays.asList(topics).contains("Custom")) { p.user.sendPacket(-1, "Match settings are not correct or custom questions are empty or failed to load."); return; }
                            if (!password.equals("[null]")) {
                                match.password = password;
                            } else match.password = "";
                            match.name = matchname;
                            match.time = time;
                            match.maxquestions = count;
                            match.topics.clear();
                            for (String topic : topics) {
                                switch (topic) {
                                    case "General":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.General);
                                        break;
                                    case "Technology":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Technology);
                                        break;
                                    case "History":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.History);
                                        break;
                                    case "Geography":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Geography);
                                        break;
                                    case "Sport":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Sport);
                                        break;
                                    case "Custom":
                                        match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Custom);
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        p.user.sendPacket(-1, "Match settings are not correct or custom questions are empty or failed to load.");
                                        return;
                                }
                            }
                            match.sendPacketAll(20, match.name,Integer.toString(match.time), Integer.toString(match.maxquestions), match.getTopicString());
                        } else {
                            p.user.sendPacket(-1, "Match settings are not correct or custom questions are empty or failed to load.");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 30: { //match start
                    if (p.user.match != null && !p.user.match.ingame && p.user == p.user.match.host) {
                        if (p.user.match.userList.size() > 1) {
                            p.user.match.start();
                        } else {
                            p.user.match.chatMessage("Not enough players to start the match!");
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 31: { //question answer
                    if (p.user.match != null && !p.user.match.usersAnswer1.contains(p.user) && !p.user.match.usersAnswer2.contains(p.user) && !p.user.match.usersAnswer3.contains(p.user) && !p.user.match.usersAnswer4.contains(p.user)) {
                        if (p.content[0].equals("1")) {
                            p.user.match.usersAnswer1.add(p.user);
                        }
                        if (p.content[0].equals("2")) {
                            p.user.match.usersAnswer2.add(p.user);
                        }
                        if (p.content[0].equals("3")) {
                            p.user.match.usersAnswer3.add(p.user);
                        }
                        if (p.content[0].equals("4")) {
                            p.user.match.usersAnswer4.add(p.user);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 50: { //chat message
                    if (p.user.match != null) {
                        for (User u : p.user.match.userList) {
                            u.sendPacket(50, p.user.username + ": " + p.content[0]);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                case 1000: { //add question request
                    String question = p.content[0];
                    String answer1 = p.content[1];
                    String answer2 = p.content[2];
                    String answer3 = p.content[3];
                    String answer4 = p.content[4];
                    String answerNumber = p.content[5];
                    String topic = p.content[6];
                    if (answerNumber.length() > 0 && answer1.length() > 0 && answer2.length() > 0 && answer3.length() > 0 && answer4.length() > 0 && question.length() > 0 && question.length() < 301 && answer1.length() < 51 && answer2.length() < 51 && answer3.length() < 51 && answer4.length() < 51 && answerNumber.matches("^[0-9]*$") && answerNumber.length() < 2 && Integer.parseInt(answerNumber) < 5) {
                        for (Question q : ServerMatch.questions) {
                            if (q.text.equalsIgnoreCase(question)) {
                                p.user.sendPacket(-1, "This question is already in the game!");
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("questions.txt", true))) {
                            writer.write(question + ";;" + answer1 + ";;" + answer2 + ";;" + answer3 + ";;" + answer4 + ";;" + answerNumber + ";;" + topic + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                            writer.close();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            CustomLog.error("Failed to write custom question!");
                            ex.printStackTrace(System.out);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
                }
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientConnected(User u) {
        if(Server.debugMode) CustomLog.info("Client has connected: " + u.socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
        usersOnline.add(u);
        this.sendPacket(0, null, u.socket);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientDisconnected(User u) {
        usersOnline.remove(u);
        u.disconnectMatch();
        if(!u.socket.isClosed())
        {
            try {
                u.socket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                CustomLog.error(ex.getMessage());
            }
        }
        if(Server.debugMode) CustomLog.info("Client has disconnected: " + u.socket.getInetAddress().getHostAddress());
    }

    private ArrayList<Question> parseQuestions(String str) {
        ArrayList<Question> list = new ArrayList();
        try {
            for (String s : str.split(";;")) {
                s = s.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
                if (!s.equals("")) {
                    String[] question = s.split(";");
                    if (Arrays.asList(question).contains("")) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if(Integer.parseInt(question[5]) < 5 && Integer.parseInt(question[5]) > 0)
                    list.add(new Question(question[0], question[1], question[2], question[3], question[4], Integer.parseInt(question[5]), Question.Topic.Custom));
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            return null;
        }
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            return list;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

If you want me to show any imports or custom classes, feel free to comment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> *my code is getting pretty hard to work with.*

That's usually a sign that your code smells (*excuse the expression*).

Despite having 'Hello, World!' as my Java experience, there's quite a bit I can comment on.

---

### Overall Comments:

- Your code is aiming to do everything, all bundled  together.

You should be spreading it out a bit more.

Stop going for a [*God object*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object), and settle with a *President object* (*That's not a real thing, I was trying to be witty*).

- Why are you returning HTML in your packets ...?

HTML is for marking up pages with specific styling (`<h1>`, `<p>`), not optimised for returning data.

Consider using JSON instead, as it is designed for returning data in the form of an object.
By converting the JSON into a Java array, you can access all the properties without having to split by delimiters.

Also among the pros is that it's widely implemented across other systems, too.

HTML takes way more bytes to send data with delimiters also, meaning the response time will be slower.

- Why are you sending packets by magic numbers (*unexplained numbers*)?

First, you should define those numbers as constants.

Actually, that *would* be the thing to do. Except, using integers like that is bad practice. It's easily confusable, and unnecessarily complicated. Use strings instead of integers there.

And instead of a `switch`, use an object, and associate variables to the keys (*strings, not integers*).

---

> ```
> c.replace("<html>", "").replace("</html>", "")
> ```

Stacking `.replace`s is bad practice, use an array instead.

---

> ```
> switch (topic) {
>     case "General":
>         match.topics.add(Question.Topic.General);
>         break;
>     case "Technology":
>         match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Technology);
>         break;
>     case "History":
>         match.topics.add(Question.Topic.History);
>         break;
>     case "Geography":
>         match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Geography);
>         break;
>     case "Sport":
>         match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Sport);
>         break;
>     case "Custom":
>         match.topics.add(Question.Topic.Custom);
>         break;
>     default:
>         p.user.sendPacket(-3);
>         return;
> ```

There's better ways to do this, than to use a `switch`.

Consider an object, or something better there.

You write this more than once, also. Consider converting this into a function.

---

> ```
> if (!password.equals("[null]")) { 
>     match.password = password;
> } else match.password = "";
> ```

First, please, *please* wrap your statements in brackets, bad things can happen if you mess that up.

Consider a ternary statement instead. Ternary statements let you simplify small `if-else` statements, and even provide job security (*joke*).

For example, here, using a ternary statement, you would write:

```
match.password = password.equals("[null]") ? "" : password;
```

A ternary here too:

> ```
> if (list.size() > 0) {
>     return list;
> } else {
>     return null;
> }
> ```

into:

```
return list.size() > 0 ? list : null;
```

---

> ```
> if (p.content[0].equals("1")) {
>     p.user.match.usersAnswer1.add(p.user);
> }
> if (p.content[0].equals("2")) {
>     p.user.match.usersAnswer2.add(p.user);
> }
> if (p.content[0].equals("3")) {
>     p.user.match.usersAnswer3.add(p.user);
> }
> if (p.content[0].equals("4")) {
>     p.user.match.usersAnswer4.add(p.user);
> }
> ```

There's a better ways to approach this: `switch` (*which you seem confident with*) or `array` (*not an object, as the keys would be integers anyway*).

---

```
if (!found){
    // Lots of code here.
} else {
    p.user.sendPacket(-3);
}
```

You should be flipping things like this, so that the smaller one comes first. Especially seeing as it's a `false` test.

---

> ```
> String answer1 = p.content[1];
> String answer2 = p.content[2];
> String answer3 = p.content[3];
> String answer4 = p.content[4];
> String answerNumber = p.content[5];
> ```

1. What would happen if you wanted a 25 answer quiz? You'd have to have it all the way up to `answer25`.
2. Don't manually type out variables like that.

Use a loop (*`for` or `foreach`, whatever floats your boat*) instead.

---

Speaking of bad practice, this should really be improved:

> ```
> writer.write(question + ";;" + answer1 + ";;" + answer2 + ";;" + answer3 + ";;" + answer4 + ";;" + answerNumber + ";;" + topic + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
> ```

Fortunately, there's an easier way to do this. **Use an array**. By using an array, you can just join all the variables together with some glue (a string, in this case: `";;"`)

```
String[] items = {question, answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answerNumber, topic};
String combinedString = StringUtils.join(items, ";;");
combinedString += System.getProperty("line.separator");
writer.write(combinedString);
```

Although, using a loop here would be *much* better, it'd probably have a similar style (*each answer being added to array, that would be joined after all the elements have been iterated over*).

[See here for more info on array joining](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1515450/3296811) and the [`StringUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) class.

Or, as @Vogel612 kindly pointed out; you can use `Collections.Joining` instead:

```
String combinedString = Stream.of(items).collect(Collectors.joining(";;"));
```

---

> ```
> import java.io.BufferedWriter;
> import java.io.FileWriter;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.util.ArrayList;
> import server.engine.*;
> import java.util.Arrays;
> import java.util.concurrent.CopyOnWriteArrayList;
> import java.util.logging.Level;
> import java.util.logging.Logger;
> ```

Why is `import server.engine.*` just thrown in the middle?

Finish declaring all the `java.util`s and then declare it at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Quill already gave a really nice review about the actual implementation of your `ServerPacketHandler`. I'll try to touch upon design aspects instead, since over the sheer volume of great suggestions I lost track of what was addressed and what isn't.

That being said I strongly encourage you to post a follow-up question after incorporating the feedback you got here.

Now enough meta-talk and more design talk:

---

Let's look at the overarching structure of your code

```
public void handlePacket [...]
   container newContent
   add to newcontent

   if packet.user.isLogged
       switch case
           case 0: // lots of code
           case 1: // lots of code
   else if username is null
       switch case
           case 2: // lots of code
   else
       switch case
           case 10: // lots of code
           case 15: // lots of code
           case 16: // code
           case 20: // lots of code
           case 21: // lots of code
           case 30: // lots of code
           case 31: // lots of code
           case 50: // lots of code
           case 1000: // lots of code
end handle packet
```

whew... that's a lot of stuff you have crammed into a single method there. Others have already mentioned the Single Responsibility Principle.

> A method should do one thing, and only that, and it should do it well.

Let's throw another thing into the mix here:

> Prefer Class-Based configuration over hardcoded configuration

Now throwing these into a big pot and stirring, we get the [`Chain of Responsibility Pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern)

This pattern allows you to define a starting point for a packet, and a way to move it through a hierarchy of *possible* Handlers. The first one that can handle the packet, does so and then the packet leaves your Chain.

basically that looks like this:

```
private static final PacketHandlerChain chain = new PacketHandlerChain();

public void handlePacket(final Packet p) {
    if (!chain.handle(p)) {
        CustomLog.warning("Recieved invalid packet from ip: " + p.getIp());
    } 
}
```

that's it... Suddenly this looks a whole lot simpler, right? btw. this only means we have transferred the complexity to somewhere else, namely our `PacketHandlerChain`. You will have to maintain this chain in your code by setting a successor for each handler....

Basically what you want to do is, use a slimmed version of your PacketHandler as interface, defining something along the lines of:

```
public interface PacketChainLink {
    void setSuccessor(PacketChainLink link);
    void handle(Packet p);
}
```

restructuring your code you'd end up at a chain of something like:

> ```
> HtmlFilterLink
> LoggingLink
> UserLoginLink
> UserRegistrationLink
> UsernameSetupLink
> MatchListLink
> MatchConnectLink
> MatchDisconnectLink
> MatchCreateLink
> MatchModificationLink
> MatchStartLink
> QuestionAnswerLink
> ChatMessageLink
> QuestionRequestLink
> ```

This should allow you to separate responsibilities clearly and keep the whole thing extensible.

---

Of course this is not the only design-pattern that would be fitting here, but I personally think it's the most idiomatic for this "problem". In any way you should strive to separate out the responsibilities you're pushing into that one method. So long :)

Answer (score 2):

That's some spaghetti you've got :) Splitting it into smaller methods would be a huge improvement by itself. I would start from top to bottom, eg. I'd extract the whole code block that handles the case of user not logged in to a method. Any modern IDE should let you do that automatically.

Another thing would be to extract "magic" values and convert them into properly named constants (all these ids, password length limits, topics, regular expressions etc.)