# Game server packet handler - follow-up

Tags: java, game

This is a follow-up question: [Game server packet handler](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/101166/game-server-packet-handler)

I have applied most of the suggestions and now the code looks like this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import server.engine.*;

public class ServerPacketHandler extends PacketHandler {

    @Override
    public void handlePacket(final Packet p) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {

        ObjectValidator.getArrayHtmlFilter(p.content);

        if (p.user.isLogged) { handlePacketLogged(p); return; }

        switch (p.id) {

            case Packets.REQUEST_LOGIN: {

                p.user.id = p.content[0];
                p.user.password = p.content[1];
                Server.getUserManager().loginUser(p.user);

            break; }

            case Packets.REQUEST_REGISTER: {

                Server.getUserManager().registerUser(p.user);

            break; }

            case Packets.REQUEST_USERNAME_SETUP: {

                Server.getUserManager().setUsername(p.user, p.content[0]);

            break; }

            default: { break; }
        }
    }

    public void handlePacketLogged(final Packet p)
    {
        switch (p.id) {

                case Packets.REQUEST_MATCH_LIST: {

                    p.user.sendMatchList();

                break; }

                case Packets.REQUEST_MATCH_CONNECT: {

                    p.user.connectMatch(Integer.parseInt(p.content[0]), p.content[1]);

                break; }

                case Packets.REQUEST_MATCH_DISCONNECT: {

                    p.user.disconnectMatch();

                break; }

                case Packets.REQUEST_MATCH_CREATE: {

                    ObjectValidator.createMatch(p.user, p.content[0], p.content[1], p.content[2], p.content[3], p.content[4], p.content[5].split(";"), p.content[6]);

                break; }

                case Packets.REQUEST_MATCH_MODIFY: {

                    if (p.user.match != null && p.user==p.user.match.host && !p.user.match.ingame) {
                        p.user.match.modifyMatch(p.content[0], p.content[1], p.content[2], p.content[3], p.content[4].split(";"));
                    }

                break; }

                case Packets.REQUEST_MATCH_START: {

                    if (p.user.match != null && !p.user.match.ingame && p.user == p.user.match.host) {
                        p.user.match.start();
                    }

                break; }

                case Packets.REQUEST_MATCH_QUESTION_ANSWER: {

                    if(p.user.match != null) {
                        p.user.match.answerQuestion(p.user, p.content[0]);
                    }

                break; }

                case Packets.REQUEST_MATCH_CHAT_MESSAGE: {

                    if (p.user.match != null) {
                        p.user.match.chatMessage(p.user.username + ": " + p.content[0]);
                    }

                break; }

                case Packets.REQUEST_QUESTION_ADD: {

                    Question question = ObjectValidator.getQuestion(p.content[0], new String[] { p.content[1], p.content[2], p.content[3], p.content[4] }, p.content[5], p.content[6]);
                    if(question==null) { p.user.sendPacket(Packets.SEND_MESSAGE_ERROR, "Your question does not meet requirements."); return; }
                    Server.getFileManager().writeQuestion(question);

                break; }

                default: { break; }
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClientConnected(User u) {

        Server.getOnlineUsers().add(u);
        this.sendPacket(0, Server.getVersion(), u.socket);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClientDisconnected(User u) {

        try {
            u.disconnectMatch();
            u.isLogged = false;
            Server.getOnlineUsers().remove(u);
            if(!u.socket.isClosed()) { u.socket.close(); }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            CustomLog.error(ex.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Because I have moved a lot of code to other classes to apply the single responsibility principle, there's not much code now, so if you want to see any other classes, just comment and I will add it to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code looks much cleaner than before, (*I'm loving your implementation of the `Packets` object, it's much better than magic numbers!*) but could still use some refactoring:

---

There's empty lines all throughout this script, removing the superfluous ones would look much better.

---

> ```
>     switch (p.id) {
>
>         case Packets.REQUEST_LOGIN: {
>
>             p.user.id = p.content[0];
>             p.user.password = p.content[1];
>             Server.getUserManager().loginUser(p.user);
>
>         break; }
>
>         case Packets.REQUEST_REGISTER: {
>
>             Server.getUserManager().registerUser(p.user);
>
>         break; }
>
>         case Packets.REQUEST_USERNAME_SETUP: {
>
>             Server.getUserManager().setUsername(p.user, p.content[0]);
>
>         break; }
>
>         default: { break; }
>     }
> ```

- You don't need to wrap the `case`s in brackets, that's what the break is for; ending the `case`.
- The `break` statement is formatted to have the same indentation as the contents of the `case`

```
    switch (p.id) {
        case Packets.REQUEST_LOGIN:
            p.user.id = p.content[0];
            p.user.password = p.content[1];
            Server.getUserManager().loginUser(p.user);
            break;
        case Packets.REQUEST_REGISTER:
            Server.getUserManager().registerUser(p.user);
            break;
        case Packets.REQUEST_USERNAME_SETUP:
            Server.getUserManager().setUsername(p.user, p.content[0]);
            break;
    }
```

---

> ```
> if (p.user.match != null && p.user==p.user.match.host && !p.user.match.ingame) {
>     p.user.match.modifyMatch(p.content[0], p.content[1], p.content[2], p.content[3], p.content[4].split(";"));
> }
> ```

This is a bit unclear on what `p.content[x]` is, and could be improved if you assigned them to variables before the statement.

Also, `p.user==p.user.match.host` should have whitespace before and after the operator.

---

> ```
> default: { break; }
> ```

There's no need for an empty `default` if it does nothing. *Usually*, you might put an error handler here instead, or something similar. [See this Stack Overflow question for more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4649423/should-switch-statements-always-contain-a-default-clause).